# Solving a Nonlinear PDE with DSolve

Tags: differential-equations, nonlinear

I need to solve a nonlinear PDE and plot the solutions. I used this code:

```
pde = {D[u[x, t], {t, 1}] == (x + (1/3)*u[x, t]^3)/e^-t}; 
sol = DSolve[pde, u[x, t], {x, t}]
```

It returns an answer with InverseFunction:

```
{{u[x, t] -> 
   InverseFunction[-((
       2 Sqrt[3] ArcTan[1/Sqrt[3] - (2 #1)/(3^(5/6) x^(1/3))] - 
        2 Log[3 x^(1/3) + 3^(2/3) #1] + 
        Log[3 x^(2/3) - 3^(2/3) x^(1/3) #1 + 3^(1/3) #1^2])/(
       6 3^(2/3) x^(2/3))) &][-(e^-t/3) + C[1][x]]}}
```

I need general solutions, I tried this code:

```
implsol = sol /. {u[x, t] -> InverseFunction[f_][v_]} :> f[u] == v
```

The answer was:

```
{-((2 Sqrt[3] ArcTan[1/Sqrt[3] - (2 u)/(3^(5/6) x^(1/3))] - 
    2 Log[3^(2/3) u + 3 x^(1/3)] + 
    Log[3^(1/3) u^2 - 3^(2/3) u x^(1/3) + 3 x^(2/3)])/(
   6 3^(2/3) x^(2/3))) == -(e^-t/3) + C[1][x]}
```

I specified an initial condition u(x,0) but it returns the same problem.
Can someone please help me to find the general solutions and to plot them?

Comment: `e` should be `E`

Comment: The solution you have got is a general one.  It depends on an arbitrary function, `C[1][x]`. You are probably confused by its unusual form. However, it is right, provided you have accounted for the note @cvgmt. You can do with this funny solution everything one does with a usual solution. For example, one can print it after fixing `C[1][x]`. For example, try the following: `pde = {D[u[x, t], {t, 1}] == (x + (1/3)*u[x, t]^3)/Exp[-t]}; sol = DSolve[pde, u[x, t], {x, t}][[1, 1]]; Plot3D[u[x, t] /. sol /. C[1][x] -> 1, {t, 0, 0.01}, {x, 0, 0.01}]`.

Comment: @cvgmt yes, it is E in the original code. Thank you.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch Thank you for your answer. I can plot the solutions with this code.  Now if I change the first function in the pde to D[u[x, t], {t, 1}] == 1/2x +t+ ((1/3)*u[x, t]^3Exp[-t] ) , I get an error message.

Comment: @sm2023 This is not an error message. Such message means that Mma does not know the solution. Probably, the solution of your second equation does not exist.